# how to chain batches properly?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm trying to biuld a chain from batches but something prevents to start my 2nd batch from executing because it brings stuff from the first batch (I guess)

this is my folder structure:

```
%~dp0..\× H\
          |______ [00]\
          |         |_________________ 123.jpg
          |                            # hard.cmd
          |
          |
          |______ [00] - cópy\ 
                    |_________________ 345.jpg
                                       # hard.cmd
```

and I start in `"%~dp0..\× H\[00]\# hard.cmd"` where content of my **`# hard.cmd`** is:

```
TITLE "R"
CHCP 1250 > NUL 2>&1
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F %%a IN ('ECHO PROMPT $H ^| CMD') DO SET BS=%%a
SET "CC=- cópy"
SET "NAME=0"

:IN
   IF NOT EXIST "SOUR CE.png" ( GOTO :CHECK )
   GOTO :START

:START
   IF EXIST "SOUR CE.jpg" IF EXIST "SOUR CE.png" ( GOTO :ASK )

:ASK
   ECHO      RESET JOB ?     y / n
   SET /P "ANSWER=X%BS%                  "
   IF '%ANSWER%' == ''      GOTO :START
   IF '%ANSWER%' == 'n'     GOTO :NO
   IF '%ANSWER%' == 'y'     GOTO :YES

:NO 
   DEL /Q /A /F "SOUR CE.jpg" "%NAME%.jpg"
   GOTO :CHECK

:YES
   DEL /Q /A /F "%NAME%.jpg"
   GOTO :CHECK

:CHECK
   IF EXIST "*.jpg" IF EXIST "*.png" ( GOTO :ERROR )
   IF EXIST "%NAME%.jpg"             ( GOTO :ERROR )
   GOTO :CONTINUE

:CONTINUE
   IF EXIST "*.jpg" ( IF NOT EXIST "SOUR CE.jpg" ( REN "*.jpg" "SOUR CE.jpg" ) )
   IF EXIST "SOUR CE.jpg" ( app.exe -i "SOUR CE.jpg" -o "%NAME%.jpg"
                           GOTO :NEXT )
   GOTO :NEXT

:ERROR
   ECHO this is error
   PAUSE > NUL
   GOTO :NEXT

:NEXT
   IF EXIST   "%~dp0..\[00] %CC%\"     (
   CALL       "%~dp0..\[00] %CC%\# hard.cmd"
   IF EXIST   "%~dp0..\[00] %CC%"  ( REN "%~dp0..\[00] %CC%"  "[02]" ) )
   ECHO DONE
```

note that content of **both** batches **(# hard.cmd)** is **same**

if I run these batches separately then they execute as they should, however if I try to chain them as demonstrated above then pops up **:ERROR** label of the second batch even if the 2nd batch/folder doesnt violte the set of rules. and as result 2nd batch shall not execute as it should (as the first one)

apart of **CALL**ing I tried even **START**ing, but non of my tries worked. these are the things I already tried:

```
CALL                      "%~dp0..\[00] %CC%\# hard.cmd"
START CALL                "%~dp0..\[00] %CC%\# hard.cmd"
START "" CALL             "%~dp0..\[00] %CC%\# hard.cmd"
START "" CMD /C           "%~dp0..\[00] %CC%\# hard.cmd"
START "" CMD /K           "%~dp0..\[00] %CC%\# hard.cmd"
START "" /WAIT  /B        "%~dp0..\[00] %CC%\# hard.cmd"
START "" /WAIT /B       /D"%~dp0..\[00] %CC%" "# hard.cmd"
START "" /WAIT /B CALL    "%~dp0..\[00] %CC%\# hard.cmd"
```

and few more combinations... where did I make a mistake ? all I want is to run 2nd batch separately after the 1st one shall finish. **preferable in the same window** (but if that is not possible then 1st batch/window shall open 2nd batch /window and first one will close right afer 2nd one starts running)

as I see it then 2nd batch brings ruleset from 1st batch, because when the 1st batch finish then in folder [00] there is a file "0.jpg" and this triggers the `:ERROR` label of the 2nd batch.

thank you to reading this and for any help

Comment: You have a lot of implicitness in these scripts.... It seems that the `:ERROR` routine is called if either of these two conditions are TRUE.... **1.)** if both any `.jpg` and `.png` files exist in the `~\[00] - cópy` folder or **2.)** if `0.jpg` exists in the `~\[00] - cópy` folder. Does that sound correct? Consider redoing your logic to be more explicit and pass in variables with a `CALL` for the paths, etc. and you could likely use one script for both/all folders rather than having the same logic in multiple scripts if you continue having trouble—being explicit always works well for me.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT yes, that is correct. I needed to build OR switch so if folder have both (*,jpg and *.png then) OR if "%NAME%.jpg" id in the folder then I want to end it with :ERROR label. I am explicitly looking for executing these batches separatly from each other. how come there is no way how to achieve this? I really feel I just missing some important minority in :NEXT label where I try to CALL/START for the next batch

Comment: To test, rather than using `"%~dp0..\[00] %CC%\# hard.cmd"` use `C:\Folder\path\× H\[00]\# hard.cmd` explicitly like that for each rather than the `"%~dp0..\~` and see if that resolves it. If so, then check those variables with `%~dp0..` and echo those to see if they are correct or what. Just an idea but I can only assume it's something related to that, or the `#` sign in the cmd file name or something along those lines. I'm not sure without digging into it with more detail but I'm tight on time right now. I thought the issue was going to `:ERROR` initially so that's why I asked about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the missing piece **`PUSHD "%~dp0..\[00] %CC%\"`**:

```
:NEXT
   IF EXIST   "%~dp0..\[00] %CC%\"     (
   PUSHD      "%~dp0..\[00] %CC%\"
   CALL       "%~dp0..\[00] %CC%\# hard.cmd"
   IF EXIST   "%~dp0..\[00] %CC%"  ( REN "%~dp0..\[00] %CC%"  "[02]" ) )
   ECHO DONE
```